# I would like to add radio button in web2py auth

Tags: authentication, radio-button, web2py

Hi I am having trouble with adding radio button in web2py auth.

As you know that web2py has built-in login feacture auth().

In db.py,

I add following

```
from gluon.tools import Auth
auth = Auth(db)
auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user']= [Field('Status')]
auth.define_tables(username=True)
```

This gives me additional text box called "Status"
I would like to change this field, so that an user can chooses only either "student" or "tutor".

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining a field, you can specify a form widget as well as a validator. In this case:

```
Field('Status', requires=IS_IN_SET(['Student', 'Tutor']),
      widget=SQLFORM.widgets.radio.widget))
```

By default, if you specify an `IS_IN_SET` validator, you will get a `<select>` widget in the form, but the above overrides the default widget by explicitly setting the radio widget.